# How to upload images from gallery using android webview

Tags: android, android-webview, android-gallery

I use one simple `WebView` to display an specific web page and that web page allows you to publish one little article and I would like to include one or more images with it.

When I click the uploading button, it doesn't respond.

Code below at `MainActivity.java` :

```
package es.bzar.bzar;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String url = "http://stackoverflow.com";

    WebView view  = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    view.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

try to use webChromeClient:

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: It doens't work, the button stills giving no respons to that action